# Johnny Ohm and the Danger Canoes

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

[image: Johnny Ohm and the Danger Canoes]

Clues: [electricity symbol]  w/i-t=___ 
[two canoes] [odd shape that resembles a bear head]

Instructions: Name That Place

_ _ _ _ _ F F _ _ _

Comment: This might be more difficult than 1-star. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Just wanted to say that rot13(hz npghnyyl, gv'f pnyyrq TRBET buz... naq nffhzvat gur ryrpgevpvgl flzoby zrnaf ibygntr, ol uvf ynj, jr unir ej - g, juvpu fbhaqf yvxr 'ebhgr' be 'ebj')

Comment: Is there any correlation with the Marvel villain?

Comment: No correlation with Marvel villain.

Comment: Hint: rot13: guvf chmmyr cebterffrf yrsg gb evtug

Comment: I can't wait for a new episode of that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although my guess requires we're mixing quantities and units with impunity, and upper and lower cases just as much, I think we're canoeing on the

> Pacific ocean

Because

> "Electrically dangerous" "Watt" (W) divided by "current" (Capital I, represented as "i" in the question) leaves either "potential difference" or "Volt",

and subtracting a T from the more likely option leaves us with

> Vol + canoes.

The odd shape is actually

> a map

presenting a lot of those:

> [image]

<sub>(The image, conveniently containing the solution in words, is from [Openclipart](https://openclipart.org/detail/341751/pacific-ring-of-fire) and in Public Domain)</sub>

Comment: You're sooooo close!

Comment: Why not canoeing on rot13(Evat bs Sver) itself, instead of the pacific ocean? that fits exactly with the _____FF___

Comment: Like I said in the comments, 'Ohm' is a reference to rot13(Trbet Buz, na ryrpgevp culfvpvfg jub qvfpbirerq 'Buz'f ynj')

Comment: @Lezzup because if it's the Pacific ocean, then the canoes are available for canoeing. If it's the thing that's written in the big bold letters in the picture and named as the answer in the text below the image, then the canoes have been used as a wordplay, and are no longer available.

Comment: @Bass, exactly. Canoes are just wordplay to get the Ibypnabrf, thats why the question is not 'where are you canoeing', but in general 'name that place'.

Comment: @Lezzup I have absolutely no idea what you are babbling on about. The place is well and properly named in the final spoiler block.

Comment: So to be clear, your final answer is Ring of fire, not Pacific ocean, right?

Comment: @newQOpenWid No, my answer is obviously "South Sandwich", because it fits the "ten letters with a double f near the middle" clue so well.

Comment: You got it! NOW PLOP THE BIG RED TEXT ON THE MAP TO GET THE CHECKMARK AND FIT THE LETTERS!

Comment: @1357924680a Yes, I know I got it. Plopping any text already in my answer isn't going to improve it, no matter what plopping means. Even though OP may a bit limited in their ability to read text in an image, that doesn't change the fact that they are free to (not) award any checkmarks based on whichever criteria they choose.